# Giving Blocks a Fixed Width

Tags: blocks

Hello i am having a few problems with 3 menu blocks i have in a region of my theme. You can view this region on the main top of this page
http://onlinebanter.com/latest

The top block just consists of 3 menu items and when you click one the child items appear (seperate menu block level). They appear to the right of the lower level menu block though.

Ive tried giving the first menu block a fixed width

.menu-block-14 {
width:500px;
}

To see if that will 'push the other menus down' but to no avail.

Can anyone suggest something for me to try?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

.menu-block-12,
  .menu-block-14 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
  }